# System.Data.DataRowView in Text Box and not default Value

Tags: c#

Please can someone help me with why I get "System.Data.DataRowView" in my text box to start and not "44" which is what I expected to see? If select it again from the drop down list then it does populate the field for me. I have tried reading many forums.

Again Thank you

```
private void E164Convertor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("CountryName");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("CountryCode");



            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

            dt.Rows.Add("United Kingdom" ,"44");
            dt.Rows.Add("United States" , "1");

            cbxctry.DataSource = dt;

            cbxctry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
            cbxctry.ValueMember = "CountryCode";

        }

        private void cbxctry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         txtctrycode.Text = cbxctry.SelectedValue.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: I tried your code and everything works perfectly fine. Did you set up some other settings such as properties of the combobox?

Comment: I have not set any I know of but will double check..  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be your issue here:

[SelectedValue Casting Issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f5e6672c-f8ab-4fc8-bda9-2542d8c78776/)

> if you want to get the value, change the ComboBox.SelectedValue type to System.Data.DataRowView.

```
System.Data.DataRowView selectedObj = cmb_Companies.SelectedValue as System.Data.DataRowView;
string str_AccountNo = selectedObj != null? selectedObj["Account_Number"].ToString():String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swap

```
cbxctry.DataSource = dt;

cbxctry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
cbxctry.ValueMember = "CountryCode";
```

like this

```
cbxctry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
cbxctry.ValueMember = "CountryCode";

cbxctry.DataSource = dt;
```

this should help